# Remove Dynamic Query string from Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to remove part of a dynamic URI from Apache. I tried different rewrite rules but I'm not getting anywhere. I was able to clean the URL using query string but that
deletes anything after `accessdenied` but we need group part for application to work.

The URI ends with:

> `accessdenied?group=test&oam_res=...`

Whatever comes after `&oam_res` should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit vague, but I guess this is going to point you into the right direction:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]*&)*oam_res=
RewriteRule ^/?accessdenied$ /accessdenied?%1 [R=301]
```

Note that this implements an *external* redirection, so it changes the URL visible in the client (browser). If you only want to do an *internal* rewrite then you need to replace the `[R=301]` flag with the `[L]` flag.

For this to work you obviously need to have the rewriting module installed, loaded and enabled in your http server. In case you want to use a dynamic configuration file (`.htaccess`) you need to enable its interpretation too using the `AllowOverride` directive. But you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only supported as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).